# centering some content in a div, floating content on same line - keeping vertical alignment

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a dynamic width.  In that div I'd like one block of content to be centered and another block of content to be floated to the right and to stay inline.

Not a great description, I know. Hopefully, you can get a better idea by looking [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zTNL8/)

I'd like the text to be inline with the flag.

Any suggestions?

Also I've realised my questions title is a bit horrible - suggestions for an edit welcome.

Comment: Why not just put a BR to make it under the flag?

Comment: I want it to float to the right, next to the flag. Vertically aligned. Not under it.

Comment: If you don't want to use positioning you can do it this way: http://jsfiddle.net/sl1dr/zTNL8/3/ It uses an extra div though.

Comment: Thanks joshuan, that's what I'd normally do but I'm finding that I'm becoming overly reliant on nesting divs for any CSS issue. I think I'd prefer to have a messy CSS file than messy HTML with extra divs. I'd be interested to hear what people feel is the better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/tw16/sGC7d/ ?

```
.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid #020202;
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
}

.numbers {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 4px;
}
```

Comment: that's it exactly thanks. Normally, I try to stay away from absolute positioning, but I can't see any issue with using it here. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/zTNL8/2/

```
.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid #020202;
    position: relative
}
.flag {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 4px 0px;
    width: 35px;
}
.flag img {
    display: block
}
.numbers {
    visibility: visible;
    line-height: 23px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking, same as tw16's answer. Who got in just before you. Shame I can't mark 2 answers.

Comment: That's fine. We both had virtually the same idea.